# Qt project release ubuntu - error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Widgets.so.5

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

I want to release my project written with Qt to a Ubuntu / Linux user. If they try to execute the build release version they get this error message, because they have not installed Qt:

> error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Widgets.so.5:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Is there a way to add all the libraries such as `libQt5Widgets.so.5` to the folder where the executable is, just like under Windows with `qt.conf`, where you can specify the `Plugins` folder?

Comment: Not clear what you mean with 'adding the libraries to the folder where the library is'. Do you mean where your application resides? And then you mention `just like under windows with qt.conf`. I suppose that you want to copy the Qt libraries to a folder and then tell the application where the libraries reside?

Comment: @KurtPattyn `I suppose that you want to copy the Qt libraries to a folder and then tell the application where the libraries reside?` Thats exactly what I want.

Comment: How did you solve this mate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be simplest to package the project using Ubuntu's package management system. The Qt dependency will then be automatically installed by the package manager when your project is installed. That'd be the best way to go about it, as long as there is a version of Qt 5 available in Ubuntu's package repository. It'll save you a whole lot of grief.

Comment: So you mean just `sudo apt-get install libqt5`?

Comment: Yes, and you should make your own project available as an apt package, dependent on libqt5. Then when your package is installed, libqt5 should be pulled in automatically.

Answer (score 14):

Try this

> sudo apt-get install libqt5widgets5

Answer (score 3):

One solution could be:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/dir/with/libs:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

But a proper solution would be to install QT libraries in system and/or package your app for Ubuntu (in your case).

Comment: That can't be automatically done, right? Because it depends where the user put the program.

Comment: Of course you can, just provide an script to start your app, where the library path is your current directory.

Answer (score 1):

I had recently updated the Android tools via the SDK manager when I saw this error.

Re-install the SDK tools to fix. That is what worked for my machine.